# Encapsulate Google Map V.3 event to listen object methods

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3

I want to encapsulate google map polygon(google.maps.Polygon) and map (google.maps.Map) into a javascript object and handle some event for both polygon and map. Here is some code

```
function Landmark(map, polygon) {
    this.map = map;
    this.polygon = polygon;

    // Add a listener for the click event
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', this.addPoint);
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.polygon, 'click', this.addPoint);

    addPoint = function (event) {
        alert("xxx");
    }
}
```

I called the function using :

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875);
    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 5,
                        center: myLatLng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    polygonInTest = new google.maps.Polygon({
                                                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                                                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                                                strokeWeight: 2,
                                                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                                                fillOpacity: 0.35
                                            });

    polygonInTest.setMap(map);

    var landmark = new Landmark(map, polygonInTest);
```

But when I trigger the event, by clicking the map, I got this error from firebug :

```
f.e is undefined
[Break On This Error] function de(a,b){var c,d=a.__e3_||{};i...n"+b]=c,c=new ce(a,b,c,3));return c};
```

Can anyone point me where have I done wrong and give some suggestions? Any comment or help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that when you are creating an event listener

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', this.addPoint);
```

your handler is not yet defined (i.e. you define `addPoint` later), so at the time of `addListener()` call `this.addPoint` is `undefined`. And GMaps messes up later when the time comes for the handler to be called.

At least that's how I realized I had a problem at this point by looking at your code :)